# ajax error with openscholar profile in Drupal

Tags: ajax, drupal, installation

Creation of a Drupal 7.19 website for OpenScholar 3.x failed with message: "The website encountered an error while retrieving /install.php?profile=openscholar&locale=en&id=1&op=finished" .

This appeared during the "install profile" phase on Lion, with MAMP despite php max_execution_time = 240 and memory_limit = 128 MB; after >80% of modules were installed, and just after the Google_Analytics module was installed. (Same happened, exactly, with .gitignore there or not; and with max_execution_time = 30). Used git to place OpenScholar stuff in the Drupal profile directory, and that seems correct, since ~80% of OpenScholar modules were found and reportedly installed.

Is there a fix to use at my end, or is this an error in OpenScholar 3.x (which is not yet available in production version, but seems to work for other people)?

I've received suggestions to delete os_ga from the openscholar.info file and to delete the install file. After I did both (either, alone, failed) the installation went through to completion. However many strict warnings appeared. I have not yet tried to bring in the ga (Google Analytics) module independently of the OpenScholar profile approach.

In any case, this experience may be useful to others.